# 408 Timeout in NodeJS app requesting Github API

Tags: node.js, http, https, github-api

Following the [documentation of the Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization) to create an authorization for a NodeJS app.

I have the following code:

```
var _options = {
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': app.get('ORGANISATION')
  },
  hostname: 'api.github.com'
};

var oauth2Authorize = function () {
  var path = '/authorizations?scopes=repo';
  path +=    '&client_id='+ app.get('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID');
  path +=    '&client_secret='+ app.get('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET');
  path +=    '&note=ReviewerAssistant';

  _options.path = path;
  _options.method = 'POST';

  var request = https.request(_options, function (response) {
    var data = "";

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });

  request.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('Problem with request: '+ error);
  });
};
```

And all I get is:

```
408 Request Time-out
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
```

Doing a `GET` request works though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`http.request()` doesn't immediately send the `request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback):

> With `http.request()` one must always call `req.end()` to signify that you're done with the request - even if there is no data being written to the request body.

It opens the underlying connection to the server, but leaves the `request` incomplete so that a body/message can be sent with it:

```
var request = http.request({ method: 'POST', ... });

request.write('data\n');
request.write('data\n');
request.end();
```

And, regardless of whether there's anything to `write()` or not, you must call `end()` to complete the `request` and send it in its entirety. Without that, the server will eventually force the open connection to close. In this case, with a `408` response.

Comment: I am an idiot. I read about that 2 weeks ago and i forgot... Thanks!